# Need assistance with htaccess

Tags: apache

I am a little confused when it comes to .htaccess . So I have a project and in the project, I have everything organized into sub folders. The way I have .htaccess written right now, it is only pulling the first portion of my url. How can I get the second portion of the URL? [www.website.com/profile/12345](http://www.website.com/profile/12345) . I am trying to get the numbers but I am currently only getting up to profile. The numbers being an ID number from the database.

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'first portion' of your URL is called the Host Name i.e. [www.website.com](http://www.website.com)

The 'second portion' of your URL is called the Path i.e. /profile/12345

You are trying to get numbers, is nonsense, it does not make sense.

Apache rewrite rules do not get numbers, rewrite rules take one URL and rewrite it into another URL based on defined conditions/criteria.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't too clear on the numbers part. When I say numbers, I mean the numbers being an ID number. So typically, a non written URL would be www.website.com/profile?id=12345 but I am trying to get it to look like www.website.com/profile/12345